# Flutter error: W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

Tags: flutter, dart, inputconnection

I have a Flutter error:

```
W/IInputConnectionWrapper: getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
```

It occurs when I clear the text in the TextField from TextEditingController input.

This is my clear text function, it works:

```
_onClear() {
setState(() {
  WidgetsBinding.instance
      .addPostFrameCallback((_) => _textController.clear());
});
}





child: TextField(
                    maxLines: 2,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    autofocus: false,                      //setting this to true,false, or removing has no effect
                    controller: _textController,                       
                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(                          
                      labelText: "Enter",
                      hintText: "Enter",
                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, color: 
Colors.blueGrey),                         
                      suffix: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.cancel),
                        onPressed: _onClear,
                      ),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: 
BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )), //textfield
```

The user can type in the textfield, click on an image (UrlLauncher), and return to the form and still see the same text input in the text field. Everything works the ways it should, and the app runs without other errors.

Is this error something I have to worry about, will I still be able to submit the final app to the store with an error, or does it have to be correct? I have no clue how to do that. Pardon my lack of knowledge, I am just trying to learn all this and am stumped. There appears to be no other answers to this question regarding Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP Script for Insert Data  then may be you are missing quote like **'$FiledName'** .Beacause this worked for me after correct it.Thanks